# I want my three textViews have the same size

Tags: ios, swift

I see this error, when I click the 'aaa view' on the simulator. 'mySecondCustomView' is the container view of them.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

my code is below.

```
aaa.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
aaa.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
aaa.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
aaa.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
aaa.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
aaa.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.heightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

bbb.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:aaa.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
bbb.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
bbb.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aaa.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
bbb.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aaa.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

ccc.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:bbb.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
ccc.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
ccc.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
ccc.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints are over-defined. For example in `aaa` You define both top/bottom + height and leading/trailing + width.
At the same time you contrain `aaa` to be the same width as `bbb` and `bbb` to be the same width as `aaa`. These are unnecessary duplicate constraints.

Remove those lines and it should work:

```
aaa.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
aaa.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.heightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

EDIT:

I played around with this and think I know what your problem is. You probably still have an autoresizing mask. Try this:

```
aaa.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bbb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
ccc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

aaa.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
aaa.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
aaa.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
aaa.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

bbb.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:aaa.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
bbb.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
bbb.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aaa.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
bbb.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aaa.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

ccc.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:bbb.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
ccc.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySecondCustomView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
ccc.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
ccc.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bbb.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
```

This produces this:
[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help :)